# Building high traffic sites with cakephp

Tags: cakephp, php

Is it good to build a high traffic sites using CakePHP? I am using CakePHP for several projects, but they're very low traffic. Any examples of such site or how can I improve the performance?

Comment: Cake can be made to handle high traffic sites, just as anything else. In the worst case by throwing lots of hardware at it. This is too broad a question. Build something, test it, profile it, define the bottlenecks, *then* ask a question how to speed up a particular part that's giving you problems.

Comment: Depends on you're definition of high-traffic too. For real high traffic sites, they will have their own VERY LIGHT framework - nothing as bloated as Cake/Codeigniter etc, and it's also down to server configuration too... I.e. using alternative HTTP servers (lighthttpd) and Database solutions (NoSQL-dbs etc depending on requirements).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This video](http://tv.cakephp.org/video/CakeFoundation/2010/12/24/andy_gale_-_cakephp_at_massive_scale_on_a_budge) probably sums up the answer for you (and gives a lot of good details / information) on "[CakePHP at massive scale on a budget](http://tv.cakephp.org/video/CakeFoundation/2010/12/24/andy_gale_-_cakephp_at_massive_scale_on_a_budge)"

It talks about how they use CakePHP on VERY HIGH traffic site, how it worked, and how it ran...etc.

I believe it was on 1.2 or 1.3 as well, which is significantly slower than 2.0, so - yes - CakePHP is a completely valid option for high-traffic sites.  Obviously sites like Facebook will have their own lighter, in-house framework, but - I think that's a problem not worrying about until you reach that point (and by then you'll be a millionaire anyway and won't care) :)